# Cordova code share mobile app and web app

Tags: angularjs, cordova

I have been developing a mobile app using Cordova and angular js. Now I'm thinking to create one web app. I want to reuse the existing mobile app code to web app. What will be the best practice to do this?

Thank you.

Comment: Take out root www folder and try to run index.html file, it will give you some error and you will have check for work around it. Plugins won't work at all. Also you may encounter CORS error. For that add header in API side.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @HardikVaghani. I too thought this. But is there any other standard approach to make use of the existing code.

Comment: try adding platform `browser` might find something useful.